# Why don't floated elements take up entire screen width?

Tags: css, css-float

I thought I had CSS floats figured out but apparently I don't because I can't figure out why this page is behaving the way it is.  I'd like for the photo and status divs to each take up 50% of the screen such that both of them appear on the same line and that line takes up 100% of the screen.  But what is happening is that the "Stats" div renders below the "Photos" div.  The only way I can get them to render on the same line is to reduce their respective widths to 49% (or lower) but then there's a slight gap between the right edge of "Stats" and the edge of the screen.  There's something that's taking up additional room but I don't know what it is and I don't see anything in Chrome's Dev Tools.  By the way, reset.css is just Meyer's reset.

Thanks.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My layout</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content-main">
        <div class="photos">Photos</div>
        <div class="stats">Stats</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**base.css**

```
.content-main {
    width: 100%;
}

.photos {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: #cf6;
}

.stats {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: #bbb;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me without any of the stuff you have in the document head. http://jsfiddle.net/6w4rj2gc/

Comment: You probably have some margin or padding or border defined somewhere in base.css.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error.  If add additional padding to each of the elements, that creates the problem.  I left that out of my question so that code shown above will work.  My bad.

Comment: If you want to include padding/borders without it affecting your total width you can try `box-sizing: border-box;`. This makes it so that the width includes padding and border